# How many integer solutions to$ x+y+z \le 6$ where $x,y,z$ are non-negative?

Tags: probability, inequality, permutations

I understand the steps towards working this question out if $x + y + z = 6$, but what are the steps for an inequality?

Comment: Hint: the difference between the number of solutions for $x + y + z \leq 6$ and the number for $x + y + z \leq 5$ is precisely the number of solutions for $x + y + z = 6$. This gives you a recurrence relation.

Comment: Another hint: You can consider all possible sums $\le6$, with all $x,y,z$ non-negative integers and apply combinatorics.

Comment: Thank you for your input, still not entirely sure where to begin

Comment: You can also add another variable $w$, and solve for the number of ways you can write $x + y + z + w = 6$.

Comment: Thank you Tunococ that's a good idea

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). First, rephrase the question to make it an equality:

> Find the number of solutions $(w, x, y, z)$ such that $w + x + y + z = 6$ and $w, x, y, z$ are non-negative integers.

To apply stars and bars, you transform $(w, x, y, z)$ so that they are *positive* integers.

> Find the number of solutions $(w, x, y, z)$ such that $(w + 1) + (x + 1) + (y + 1) + (z + 1) = 10$ and $(w + 1), (x + 1), (y + 1), (z + 1)$ are positive integers.

This gives $\binom{9}{3}$ as the answer.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your explanation. What equation did you use to come to 9 choose 3?

Comment: @BarneyChambers That is from the stars and bars principle. You're placing 3 bars in 9 positions to separate 10 (linearly placed) items into 4 groups.

Comment: Is this for "Positive Integers" or "Non negative"? It looks like this doesn't work for x,y,z = 0? Am I right?

Comment: @BarneyChambers The stars and bars principle only works for positive integers. That is why I need to transform the problem first. The transformed problem has the same answer as the original problem. (Please read carefully.)

Answer (score 3):

The number of solutions of the inequality $x + y + z \leq 6$ in the non-negative integers is equal to the number of solutions of the equation $x + y + z + w = 6$ in the non-negative integers since $w = 6 - (x + y + z)$ represents the difference between $6$ and the actual sum.

A solution can be represented by placing three $+$ signs in a list of six ones.  For instance, the solution $x = 2$, $y = 1$, $z = 0$, $w = 3$ of the equation $x + y + z + w = 6$ can be represented as

$$1 1 + 1 + + 1 1 1$$

Equivalently, it represents the solution $x = 2$, $y = 1$, $z = 0$ of the inequality $x + y + z \leq 6$.

Note that a plus sign before all the ones indicates that $x = 0$ and a plus sign after all the ones indicates that $w = 0$.  Consecutive addition signs indicate that the variable that would go between the addition signs is equal to zero.

Each list contains nine symbols, the six ones and the three plus signs. The number of solutions to the inequality $x + y + z \leq 6$ or, equivalently, the equation $x + y + z + w = 6$ is the number of ways you can place three plus signs in a list of six ones and three plus signs, which is

$$\binom{9}{3} = \frac{9!}{3!(9 - 3)!} = \frac{9!}{3!6!} = \frac{9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7}{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = 84$$

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

$x$ can be anything from $0$ to $6$.
$y$ can be anything from $0$ to $6 - x$.
$z$ can be anything from $0$ to $6 - (x+y)$

$$\begin{align} 
\text{total} &= \sum_{x=0}^6 \quad \sum_{y=0}^{6-x}\quad \sum_{z=0}^{6-(x+y)} 1
\\ &\quad \text{...and the rest is just algebra}
\\ &= \sum_{x=0}^6 \quad \sum_{y=0}^{6-x} 6-(x+y) + 1
\\ &= \sum_{x=0}^6 \left(\sum_{y=0}^{6-x} 7 - x\right) - \left(\sum_{y=0}^{6-x}y\right)
\\ &= \sum_{x=0}^6  (6 - x + 1)(7 - x) - \left(\frac{(6-x)^2 + (6-x)}2\right)
\\ &= \frac 12 \sum_{x=0}^6 x^2 - 15x + 56
\\ &= \frac 12\left( \sum_{x=0}^6 x^2 - 15\sum_{x=0}^6x + \sum_{x=0}^6 56 \right)
\\ &= \frac 12\left( \frac{6(6+1)(2\cdot 6 + 1)}{6} - 15 \frac{6(6+1)}2 + 56\cdot(6+1) \right)
\\ &= 84
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Consider $x+y+z=0 \implies x=y=z=0$ (that's one solution)

Consider $x+y+z=1$. There is only one way to produce 1, and this way is $1+0+0=1$. Though, the number 1 in the sum can hold 3 places (e.g. $1+0+0$ or $0+1+0$ or $0+0+1$). As you can see, order matters. So you take  3 different solutions.

$(x,y,z)=(1,0,0)$

$(x,y,z)=(0,1,0)$

$(x,y,z)=(0,0,1)$

You can go on with $x+y+z=2$. There are 2 fundamental ways (and their respective permutations) to construct this sum, which are $2+0+0$ and $1+1+0$....

Comment: So, you basically do x+y+z = 1,2,3,4,5 and finally 6, then add them all up together?

Comment: That's the point. But there's no need to get all this procedure done. You only need to count permutations.

Comment: Did you get 208 by any chance?

Comment: The correct answer is 84.

Comment: Nope, just $84=\binom 9 3$, as Tunococ suggested.